# Setting and activate a Multitech Conduit at Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, conduit

I have a MultiTech Conduit Gateway and try to activate it at BlueMix.

I have created two Conduit devices.

However, the Conduit status is disconnected. How to activate it?

[image: MQTT Node at a MultiTech Conduit as Gateway mode.]

```
Broker = epbb4j.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com
Client ID = g:epbb4j:Multitech_Conduit:Conduit002
Username = use-token-auth
Password = (given password here).
Topic = iot-2/type/+/id/+/evt/+/fmt/+
The mqtt status = disconnected.
```

How to activate the Multitech Conduit at BlueMix?
[image: Device Status = Disconnected]

Thank you very much in advance.

Warmest Regards,
Suryadi

Comment: Is your Device ID Conduit001 or Conduit002?  Looks like you registered 001 as a gateway but are putting 002 in your node-red config.

Comment: The Conduit002 is now connected to Bluemix Cloud. But I still don't know how to connect mDot devices to Conduit Gateway.
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/288654/how-to-connect-mdot-devices-into-a-multitech-condu.html

Comment: I am assuming you mean a Multi-tech mdot device?  If your mDot device does not use MQTT protocol to communicate, then you need to send the data from that device to your gateway and use the gateway to publish the information to Watson IoT platform.  Have you contacted Multitech support about how to get data from mdot to conduit?  https://support.multitech.com/support/login.html